# eclipse configuration with pmd

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was trying to configure `PMD plugin` in eclipse (window8) but after 50% progress error occures .

i am using this in path http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

I need to configure PMD for code review, from some resource's i found pmd useful.

and it is good code analyzer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try installing the plugin using the Eclipse marketplace.

Comment: in market place there no option to install in pmd like other plugin's

Comment: What's your Eclipse version?

Comment: i am using Version: Helios Service Release 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to the Eclipse IDE, it's better to know how to install the plugin for it:

1. Start the Eclipse IDE (screenshot from the Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, version: Helios Service Release 2)
2. Select the Help –>Install New Software.... in the Eclipse menu item.
3. The install window will be open. On there, click the "Add.." button.
4. In the "Add Repository" window, enter the name and location (plugin URL)

   PMD plugin: http://pmd.sf.net/eclipse

   Then click the "OK" button.
5. Select PMD for Eclipse 3 and Apache Xerces in the "Select the features to install" list and click Next. Accept the terms of the license agreements and click Next.
6. Verify that the install location in Eclipse installation directory, otherwise select the correct one, then click Finish.

Answer (score -2):

Unable to read repository problem can come because of your internet connection or proxy.

Check if eclipse update is working.
As per your screenshots you are doing fine.
Also double check your PMD url by opening it in browser.

### PMD Installation

To install the PMD for Eclipse plugin:-

In Eclipse, click on

- Help -> Install New Software...
- Click on Add..
- Enter the following:

Name: PMD for Eclipse Update Site

URL: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/
and click OK.

- You should see PMD for Eclipse Select the checkbox next to it and
  click Next

You'll need to accept the license and confirm you want to install a plugin that is not digitally signed.

- Restart eclipse.